# Copy MySQL table in AzureTableName in java

Tags: java, mysql, azure, netbeans-8

I am creating a Java program that pulls a table from MySQL and pushes it to an Azure database.

Structure of method:

```
public void transferDataBase(String MysqlTableName, Connection MySQLConnection, String AzureTableName, Connection AzureConnection)
```

Comment: What is the questrion? What is your problem?

Comment: i want to create on method in java.  which transfer data from mySQL table to Azure table. where i passed 4  parameters. as i told.

Comment: Could you post any errors you're experiencing and the full method and maybe we could help.

Comment: thanks to all i did it.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, I think you should use the database tools to transfer a MySQL table into a Azure SQL DB table. Such as DBeaver or Kettle, they can do it well. You can download them at http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/download/ and http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/.

If you have to integrate the function into your program, there is a simple code using a Java Framework JFinal that it has the ORM like Rails ActiveRecord to implement the function easily.

I uploaded the dependent libs into OneDrive, you can download them from the url http://1drv.ms/1L81q0t.

Firstly, you need create a Azure SQL Database table with column names as the same as MySQL table.

```
    // MySQL
    String jdbcUrlMySQL = "mysql.jdbcUrl";
    String userMySQL = "mysql.user";
    String passwordMySQL = "mysql.password";
    String driverClassMySQL = "mysql.driverClass";
    C3p0Plugin cpMySQL = new C3p0Plugin(jdbcUrlMySQL, userMySQL, passwordMySQL, driverClassMySQL);
    ActiveRecordPlugin arpMySQL = new ActiveRecordPlugin("mysql", cpMySQL);
    arpMySQL.setShowSql(true);
    // SQL DB
    String jdbcUrlSqlDb = "sqldb.jdbcUrl";
    String userSqlDb = "sqldb.user";
    String passwordSqlDb = "sqldb.password";
    String driverClassSqlDb = "sqldb.driverClass";
    C3p0Plugin cpSqlDb = new C3p0Plugin(jdbcUrlSqlDb, userSqlDb, passwordSqlDb, driverClassSqlDb);
    ActiveRecordPlugin arpSqlDb = new ActiveRecordPlugin("sqldb", cpSqlDb);
    arpSqlDb.setShowSql(true);
    // Start DB Connect
    cpMySQL.start();
    arpMySQL.start();
    cpSqlDb.start();
    arpSqlDb.start();
    // Transfer
    String mysqlTableName = "mysql.table";
    String sqldbTableName = "sqldb.table";
    String sql = String.format("select * from %s", mysqlTableName);
    List<Record> list = Db.use("mysql").find(sql);
    for (Record rec : list) {
          Db.use("sqldb").save(sqldbTableName, rec);
    }
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy any database table to other database

```
public static void transferDataBase(String MysqlTableName, Connection MySQLConnection, String AzureTableName, Connection AzureConnection) 
{
    try 
    {
        PreparedStatement ps = AzureConnection.prepareStatement("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + AzureTableName);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps = MySQLConnection.prepareStatement("DESCRIBE " + MysqlTableName);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + AzureTableName + "(";

        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            String mNull, mPrimaryKey, mDef;

            if (rs.getString("null").equals("NO")) 
            {
                mNull = "NOT NULL";
            } 
            else 
            {
                mNull = "NULL";
            }

            if (rs.getString("key").equals("PRI")) 
            {
                mPrimaryKey = "Primary Key";
            } 
            else if (rs.getString("key").equals("UNI")) 
            {
                mPrimaryKey = "unique key";
            }
            else 
            {
                mPrimaryKey = "";
            }

            if (rs.getString("default") != null) 
            {
                mDef = rs.getString("default");
            } 
            else 
            {
                mDef = null;
            }

            createQuery = createQuery + rs.getString("Field") + " " + rs.getString("Type") + " " + mNull + " " + mPrimaryKey + " " + mDef + " " + rs.getString("Extra") + ",";
        }

        rs.close();

        createQuery = createQuery.substring(0, createQuery.length() - 1);
        createQuery = createQuery + ")";

        System.out.println(createQuery.toString());
        ps = AzureConnection.prepareStatement(createQuery);

        int t = ps.executeUpdate();

        if (t >= 0) 
        {
            ps = MySQLConnection.prepareStatement("select * from " + MysqlTableName);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = metadata.getColumnCount();
            AzureConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
            int recordCount = 1;
            Statement psnew = AzureConnection.createStatement();

            if (rs != null) 
            {
                while (rs.next()) 
                {
                    String sb = new String("insert into " + AzureTableName + " values(");
                    int i = 1;

                    while (i <= columnCount) 
                    {
                        sb = sb + "'" + rs.getString(i).toString() + "',";
                        i++;
                    }

                    sb = sb.substring(0, sb.length() - 1);
                    sb = sb + ")";

                    psnew.addBatch(sb);
                    recordCount++;

                    //execute and commit batch of 1000 queries
                    if (i % 1000 == 0) 
                    {
                        psnew.executeBatch();
                    }
                }

                int batchResult[] = psnew.executeBatch();
                AzureConnection.commit();
                System.out.println(batchResult.length + " Rows affected");
            } 
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("No Record in database");
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Table does not exists");
        }
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```